# Any PHP ORMs support multi-tenant databases and optimistic concurrency control?

Tags: php, orm, multi-tenant

Looks like the options are Propel, Doctrine, and ActiveRecord, others?, but I am only familiar with Yii's version of ActiveRecord.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, I get to answer my own StackOverflow question again.

Looks like Doctrine the ORM supports it:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/reference/transactions-and-concurrency.html#locking-support

As well as a PHP framework called QCu.be:

http://examples.qcu.be/assets/_core/php/examples/more_codegen/optimistic_locking.php

Ruby also supports it:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html